# How to echo an image using PHP inside an HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display JPG images into an HTML table using PHP echo. I have tried many many different methods but none correctly work. The images should be called by the corresponding $row value e.g. row 1 = 1.jpg and so on.

```
<?php
include_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id[] = implode(',',$row);
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id']. "</td>";
        echo "<td> <img src='../style/" .  $id . "'/>    </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['make']. "</td><td>" . $row['model']. "</td><td>" . $row['price']. "</td><td>" . $row['power']. "</td>";
    }
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: When you're building your source for the image: `<img src='../style/" .  $id . "'/>` there is no file extension. Have you tried adding it?

Comment: How would i do that?

Comment: please add <img src='../style/" . $id . ".jpg'/> like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using wrong variable for image path in src

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['id']. "</td>"; echo "<td> <img src='../style/" .  $row['id']  . ".jpg'/>    </td>"; echo "<td>" . $row['make']. "</td><td>" . $row['model']. "</td><td>" . $row['price']. "</td><td>" . $row['power']. "</td>";
```

Check value of src attribute in above code.

Comment: Any idea how i would resize the image within the code?

Comment: @theskyispurple If you want to resize it on webpage only you have to use css.

Comment: style = "width:50px; height:50px;" add this attribute in your img tag